# Is there a template language for ASP.NET MVC like JSTL and OGNL?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, templates, jstl, ognl

Is there a template language for ASP.NET MVC like JSTL and OGNL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any equivalent of JSTL or OGNL for Asp.Net mvc. Html helpers in most cases are sufficient.

EDIT: If the code intermingling is an issue then you should look into Spark View Engine.

http://sparkviewengine.com/

Comment: Html helpers are good enough to output HTML elements. But what about looping constructs and conditional statements. We dont want code to be intermixed in View do we? After all it was a main problem in classic ASP.

Comment: @nitroxon: Please look into my Edit. Probably you should look into Spark View Engine.

Answer (score 0):

I am brand new to ASP.NET MVC, so I can't give a detailed answer. But I do know there are other template languages such as Brail and NVelocity. I know this because ASP.NET MVC in Action goes over them in the customizing ASP.NET MVC section.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Spark View Engine](http://sparkviewengine.com/). It provides you with really clean and nice views. I've used it seriously in one major project, and I'm totally in love.